# How to upload a file to Kafka Consumer?

Tags: file, apache-kafka, flume

I am trying to load a file to Kafka Consumer either with Flume or directly to Kafka.  I started Kafka server using this link: http://kafka.apache.org/081/quickstart.html

As mentioned in the doc, I started zookeeper and also the brokers. Then I am able to send messages from Producer to Consumer. But, I am trying to see if I can upload an input file from my local machine to Kafka.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Is the file used by any of your producers or consumers?

Comment: Well, I want to pass that file from Kafka to Storm and then visualize the data.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't load a file into Kafka Consumer**. You can only write data/file in a kafka topic using Kafka Producer Api's. 
So, you need to write that file into a kafka topic and then your consumers will be able to read it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I can write a file into Kafka topic? Thanks!